# External Sharing in SharePoint On Premise 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharing

How to set up External Sharing same as Office 365 in SharePoint On Premise 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '**sharing**' options have not changed between 2013 and 2016.

You could use standard Active Directory accounts and hand those out to non-employees. This requires a Windows User CAL or External Connector (last I looked, that evens out at ~60 users). On the SharePoint side, no licensing is required.

You could also federate using Azure ACS and develop custom code to handle sharing with accounts such as Microsoft, Facebook, etc. This is a fairly high development investment, though.

MSDN Forum Link [Sharepoint Server 2016 - On Premise External Sharing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/be9d104d-6e52-4ff2-a5b9-35acc5080415/sharepoint-server-2016-on-premise-external-sharing?forum=SP2016)